# Modifying ActiveX controls through custom add-in in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on moving a worksheet into an add-in so I can make updates to the code without having to give new workbooks to everyone.  The process has been fairly straightforward until I got to the area where add-in code needs to modify ActiveX controls present on the sheet.

The previous code I was using to modify these:

```
If Sheet1.Range(RowHighlightToggle.LinkedCell).Value = True Then
    RowHighlightToggle.Caption = "Row Highlight - On"
    HighlightStatus = 0
Else
    RowHighlightToggle.Caption = "Row Highlight - Off"
    HighlightStatus = 1
End If
```

`RowHightlightToggle` being the ActiveX control in question.  I'm not sure how to refer to this button when coding inside the add-in.  I've tried doing `Sheet1.RowHighlightToggle.LinkedCell` and that is giving me an error as well.  I'm not using `Sheet1` inside the add-in as I have a function to get codenames from the target workbook so `Sheet1` is usually something like `AWSheet1` but it is a `Worksheet` variable so that is not the issue either.  I can read the linked cell value quite easy but I have no way of changing the button caption without somehow referring to the button inside the code.

This button will always be present in the workbook that this add-in is being made for, I have additional code to make sure the add-in is only visible in that workbook as well and hides itself for any others.

Is there a way to refer to the button through the add-in or possibly a way to link the caption to a cell so I can change the cell value to update the caption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more research I found out I can refer to it by using `OLEObjects`, working code including the rest of the sub is below.

```
Sub RowHighlightToggle()

'-----Startup Code--------
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayStatusBar = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With
'------------------------

Dim HighlightStatus As Long, AWSheet1 As Worksheet, ThisButton As Object

If TargetWorkbook Is Nothing Then Set TargetWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

Set AWSheet1 = GetWsFromCodeName(TargetWorkbook, "Sheet1")

Set ThisButton = AWSheet1.OLEObjects("RowHighlightToggle")

    Call Common_Functions.StartUnlock

    If AWSheet1.Range(ThisButton.LinkedCell).Value = True Then
        ThisButton.Object.Caption = "Row Highlight - On"
        HighlightStatus = 0
    Else
        ThisButton.Object.Caption = "Row Highlight - Off"
        HighlightStatus = 1
    End If

    Call Common_Functions.StartLock

    If Worksheets.Count > 6 Then
        Call Common_Functions.SheetArrayBuild(TargetWorkbook)
        For i = LBound(SheetArray) To UBound(SheetArray)
            Sheets(SheetArray(i, 1)).Range("Z1").Value = HighlightStatus
        Next i
    End If

'-----Finish Code--------
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayStatusBar = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
'------------------------

End Sub
```

And the function to get the worksheet from the workbook

```
Function GetWsFromCodeName(wb As Workbook, CodeName As String) As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
         If ws.CodeName = CodeName Then
             Set GetWsFromCodeName = ws
             Exit For
         End If
    Next ws
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the control is on Sheet1, you should be able to use:

```
Sheet1.RowHightlightToggle.Caption = "Row Highlight - On"
```

But you can also get at the control using the shapes collection:

```
Sheet1.Shapes("RowHightlightToggle").DrawingObject.Object.Caption = "Row Highlight - On"
```

Or, with a more generic workbook variable:

```
Dim userWorkbook as Workbook
Set userWorkbook = Workbooks("UserData.xlsm")
userWorkbook.Worksheets("Foo").Shapes("RowHightlightToggle").DrawingObject.Object.Caption = "Row Highlight - On"
```

Comment: `Method or data member no found.` likely due to the code not running in the actual workbook that the button is part of so I can't refer to sheets by the actual codename.

Comment: See the shapes approach that I added. The `Sheet` variable will need to refer to the target sheet.

Comment: Shapes does not work either - `The item with the specified name wasn't found.`